# Execute multiple JavaScript parallel using therubyracer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, therubyracer

I don't know much about the javascript but have very basic knowledge. I have two questions in my mind regarding therubyracer gem of rails.

My questions are:-

1. How "therubyracer" actually works? Like If we have a JavaScript written on backend and how it access that JavaScript and executes the code.
2. Can we execute multiple JavaScript parallel? If so than how? and if I use sidekiq for the same than how is it possible?

Comment: Before you get started with sidekiq (celluloid) with therubyracer, you should have a look here https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/270#issuecomment-58924834 and https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#thread-safe-libraries

Answer (score 0):

**V8** is a JavaScript engine build by google. It is open source and written in C++. It is used for both client side (Googgle Chrome) and server side (node.js) JavaScript applications.so `rubyracer` provides an interface to interact with **V8 javascript engine** where you can write js,embed ruby code and many more...

In order to excute multiple js parallely,Yes you can do it but i dont know why would you do that..its just like putting code of one js file in multiple js files and loading/executing them in a shot.....

`sidekiq` is more towards server-side than client side(javascript) as it handles backgound jobs.